# How to degrade database tier from Business Critical to General pupose

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I am a newbie to Azure.
We have a database which is under elastic pool and elastic pool is under Business Critical tier and so the databse is also a Business critical tier.
Due to pricing issue i want to downgrade both elastic pool and the associated database to General pupose.

I am looking for Azure Cli command to perform this action.

Answer (score 0):

To change the service tier of your Elastic Pool, you can use the az sql elastic-pool update command.

```bash
az sql elastic-pool update --resource-group <ResourceGroupName> --server-name <ServerName> --name <ElasticPoolName> --edition GeneralPurpose
```

Databases in an Elastic Pool inherit the pool's service tier. If you've set specific configurations on the database, you might need to update it separately using the az sql db update command.

```bash
az sql db update --resource-group <ResourceGroupName> --server-name <ServerName> --name <DatabaseName> --elastic-pool <ElasticPoolName>
```